# Remove applications from 'cmd'+'tab'

Tags: macos, dock, application-switcher

I have just started to use the <kbd>command</kbd>+(<kbd>Shift</kbd>)+<kbd>tab</kbd> shortcut for switching between apps.
The issue with this is a few applications that I have open, I hardly use or have them open in the background (I still want them open).

Is it posible to remove some of the applications from the <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> menu whilst still having them open and accessible via the Dock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the Dock and App switcher are linked together, you can't get what you want. It's unfortunate because many apps are simply background apps that are irrelevant in people's day to day workflow.

You can however, opt for a 3rd party Window Switcher, which can be configured to not show applications that have no open windows. Some people like [Witch](https://manytricks.com/witch/), I very much like [contextsformac](https://contexts.co/). I have it setup as <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>, but you can replace <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> entirely if you want.

Comment: Could you edit your post to contain the links to the applications please?

Comment: I should also add that a workaround in terms of ease of use might be to press and hold command + tab and then use mouse or touchpad to select which app to go to (rather than having to hold command and hit tab repeatedly).

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/297291/how-can-i-remove-an-app-icon-on-macs-application-switcher-cmdtab-menu